# get field names from join statement (Expand the * star)

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I'm building rather lengthy joins in ad-hoc queries lately and I find it very tedious to type out all of the field names in the select statement once my joins work.  Is there a quick way to just list out all of the field names in a combined query?  Is there some query to run against a select statement, or key command to do this?

For example, there are probably about 30 fields in the below join.  If I could get a quick list of them to expand from the '*' star then I could take away what I don't need.

```
SELECT *
FROM [DB].[THINGS].[QLINKS] Q
JOIN [DB].[THINGS].[POINTS] RQ
    ON Q.ID = RQ.POINT_ID
JOIN [DB].[THINGS].[REFERENCES] R
    ON RQ.POINT_ID = R.ID
JOIN SA_MEMBERSHIP.DBO.ASPNET_USERS U
    ON U.USERID = R.PERSON_ID
JOIN SA_MEMBERSHIP.DBO.ASPNET_MEMBERSHIP M
    ON M.USERID = U.USERID
WHERE NOT Q.ID IN (
        SELECT RQ.QLINK_ID
        FROM [DB].[DATA].[ENTRIES] E
        JOIN [DB].[THINGS].[REFERENCES] R
            ON E.PERSON_ID = R.PERSON_ID
        JOIN [DB].[THINGS].[POINTS] RQ
            ON R.ID = RQ.POINT_ID
        WHERE (
                ITEMKEY LIKE '102_0%'
                OR ITEMKEY LIKE '104_0%'
                )
            AND E.POINT_ID IS NULL
        GROUP BY E.PERSON_ID, LEFT(ITEMKEY, 5), R.ID, RQ.QLINK_ID
        )
```

Comment: The point of listing out the fields is that you probably don't want all of them.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I agree with you, the point is that, sometimes, it is easier to remove some than to add a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there is a plugin for that! The plugin ApexSQL refactor has this for free.

Direct link here:http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_refactor.aspx

Described by the venerable Pinal Dave here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/07/24/sql-server-how-to-format-and-refactor-your-sql-code-directly-in-ssms-and-visual-studio/

Answer (score 2):

something like the following (tsql version, the idea is to use metadata of the result set) with cursor c being your query

```
declare c cursor for select * from sys.databases
go
open c


DECLARE @Report CURSOR;
declare @cn sysname
declare @op int
declare @ccf int
declare @cs int
declare @dts smallint
declare @cp tinyint
declare @colsc tinyint
declare @orp int
declare @od varchar(1)
declare @hc smallint
declare @cid int
declare @oid int
declare @dbid int
declare @dbn sysname

exec sp_describe_cursor_columns @cursor_return = @Report out, @cursor_source = N'global', @cursor_identity = N'c';

declare @res nvarchar(max)
set @res = '';

FETCH NEXT from @Report into @cn, @op, @ccf, @cs, @dts, @cp, @colsc, @orp, @od, @hc, @cid, @oid, @dbid, @dbn;
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN
    set @res = @res +',' + @cn
   FETCH NEXT from @Report into @cn, @op, @ccf, @cs, @dts, @cp, @colsc, @orp, @od, @hc, @cid, @oid, @dbid, @dbn;
END

print stuff(@res, 1, 1, '')

CLOSE @Report;
DEALLOCATE @Report;
GO

close c
deallocate c
```

Comment: Ok, that is pretty cool. But it doesn't provide the table "AS"  piece.  For example RQ.field1, Q.field1...

Comment: @mcfea [sp_describe_cursor_columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms182755.aspx) should helps you doing this.

Comment: Well, I was hoping for something a little more "right clickish" but this answers my question.  TY!